# Convert ICollection to a psobject for passing to ft or export-csv

Tags: .net, powershell

I use powershell to do some ADSI/LDAP queries by invoking `DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher` as I need to provide alterative set of credentials. Once I execute a `FindAll()` method, I get a `DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection` which implements `ICollection`. From there on, if I want to pipe that output to ft or export-csv, I must create a new psobject that copies the attributes I am interested to a new PSObject like so:

```
$dEntry = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://acme.com/cn=sites,cn=configuration,dc=acme,dc=com","user","pass");
$searcher=New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($dEntry);
$searcher.Filter="(objectClass=siteLink)";
$searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("siteList");
$searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cost");
$searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("replInterval");
$searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
$searcher.FindAll() |%{
$count=$_.Properties.sitelist.Count;
$p=@{"cn"=[string]$_.Properties.cn; "sites"=$count;
    "cost"=[string]$_.Properties.cost;
    "replInterval"=[string]$_.Properties.replInterval;
    };
    if ($count>=2) { 
        $p["mesh"]=$count;
    }else{
        $p["mesh"]=$count*$count;
    }
    New-Object psobject -Property $p
}
```

This looks quite tedious and as it is probably such a common task, surely, there must be an easier way of doing that. And yes, I know of AD helper libs, but they don't help me as I need to use alternate creds and most of them break this way.

Comment: I suggest to change `($count>=2)` to `($count -ge 2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it copies any properties found on the search object to a new psobject:

```
$searcher.FindAll() | ForEach-Object {

    $pso = New-Object PSObject

    $_.PSBase.Properties.GetEnumerator() | Foreach-Object{
        Add-Member -InputObject $pso -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_.Name -Value ($_.Value | foreach {$_})
    } 

    $pso
}
```

Comment: Not brief, but best (and only) answer